# Understanding the support of a differential operator thought of as a tempered distribution from perspective of Schwartz kernel

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations, schwartz-space, microlocal-analysis

Consider the differential operator

$$ A:=\sum_{|\alpha|\leq m}a_{\alpha}(x)D^{\alpha}, $$
where $\alpha$ is a mutiindex on $\mathbb{R^n}$.

It can be checked that the Schwartz kernel of $A$ is

$$ K(x,y)=\sum_{|\alpha|\leq m}a_{\alpha}(x)(D^{\alpha}\delta)(x-y). $$

I would like to prove that

$$ \text{supp}Au\subset\text{supp}u,\quad\text{and}\quad\text{sing supp}Au\subset\text{sing supp}u, $$

where $u\in\mathscr{S}'$

From Hintz's notes (Page10) [https://people.math.ethz.ch/~hintzp/notes/micro.pdf](https://people.math.ethz.ch/%7Ehintzp/notes/micro.pdf), there states that:

From the perspective of the Schwartz kernel K of A, the first inclusion is really due to the fact that $K(x, y)$ is supported on the diagonal $x = y$, while the second inclusion is really due to the fact that $K(x, y)$ is smooth away from $x = y$. (That is, adding to $K$ an element of $\mathscr{S}(\mathbb{R}^{2n})$ preserves the second inclusion, but destroys the first inclusion.).

I don't really understand what this means, i.e., I don't know how to understand these two inclusions from perspective of Schwartz kernel. Can anyone please explain the idea behind it? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main idea is working with the formula:

\begin{equation}
Au(x)=\int K(x,y)u(y)dy
\end{equation}

and the set operation for $A\subset X\times Y$, $B\subset Y$:

\begin{equation}
A\circ B = \{x\in X : \exists y\in Y \text{ so that } (x,y)\in A,y\in B\}
\end{equation}

(draw some pictures in $X=Y=\mathbb{R}^2$ for intuition).

The formula then basically tells you that:

\begin{equation}
supp \;Au \subset supp \; K \; \circ \; supp \; u
\end{equation}
because the LHS can only be non-zero if the integrand in the RHS is at some point non-zero, but it could also happen that even with non-zero integrand, the integral vanishes (therefore $\subset$ and not $=$). Analogous reasoning with $singsupp$ instead of $supp$, since differential operators preserve smoothness and extend to distributions.

Look again at the form of $K$ and notice that $supp \; K = singsupp \; K \subset Diagonal(X\times X)$, since it is a linear combination of derivatives of delta functions in $(x-y)$, so only non-zero for $x=y$ (and always singular when non-zero).

This means $supp \; Au \subset Diagonal(X\times X) \;\circ supp \; u = supp \; u$ and same for $singsupp$. Notice that the last equality follows because in the case $X=Y$ the diagonal is a left identity for $\circ$ (check).